# How do you prevent a user program from leaving kernel resources locked?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, concurrency

Let's consider a case where a user program calls a system call that has some synchronization measures. The simplest example would be

```
rwlock_t lock; // let's assume it's initialized properly.
write_lock(&lock);
// do something...
write_unlock(&lock);
```

Now, what happens when the user program terminates after locking `lock` but before releasing it is that the `lock` becomes perpetually locked, which we do not want it to happen. What we want the kernel to do is smartly detect any hanging locks and release them accordingly. But detecting such tasks can incur too much overhead, as the system needs to periodically record and check every task for every synchronizing action.

Or perhaps we can centralize the code into another kernel thread and do synchronization job there. But invoking on another thread still requires some form of synchronization, so I don't think it is possible to completely remove synchronizing code from the user program.

I have put a lot of thought into this and tried to google for some information but I couldn't see any light on this. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: 'as the system needs to periodically record and check every task for every synchronizing action' - why?  If you want such inter-process locks released upon process termination, you only need to release them upon process termination.  Why would you need to check periodically?

Comment: @MartinJames Sorry if I wasn't clear enough but what I meant was the case where user program ends forcibly - like when user presses ctrl-c during mid-lock execution.

Comment: It should not matter how a process gets terminated.  Your kernel should release all inter-process locks as part of the usual cleanup after stopping all threads in the process.  Inter-thread locks don't need to be released since all the theads are stopped at that stage of process termination.